# Oracle forms 10, change visible elements depending on query parameters

Tags: oracleforms

I have different datablocks to show the results of a query. This query gets the input parameters from two lists selected by the user. 
I want to change the view after the query depending on the parameters introduced, so I made different tables and change the properties before showing the results.

Example:

```
IF :BLOCK.EST_TRAMITA = '1' AND :BLOCK.EST_TIPO = '2' THEN
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('FEFOR',VISIBLE,PROPERTY_TRUE);
ELSE
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('FEFOR',VISIBLE,PROPERTY_FALSE);
END IF;
```

The problem is that I have to put all the tables in the same place so the editor is getting messy. Is there a better way to change the visible elements without overlapping the tables in the editor? Thanks

Comment: How about creating a **tab layout**, so that every table gets its own tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two canvasses and each canvas on the same place.
And then use `show_view` to show the canvas you need.

You also have to take in account that you should create on the correct item a key-next-item trigger and key-prev-item and also at block level a key-nxtblk and a key-prvblk trigger. Because otherwise you could get in the items in the other canvas by going over the items or using the key next block.